# problema implementar @ViewChild

Tags: nodejs, angular8

problemas para implementar ViewChild en un proyecto de angular 8.
es la primera vez que toco angular y seguia un pequeño ejemplo.

1-cree un proyecto con:
    ng new demoApp1

2-despues genere un componente y segui los pasos deun pequeño tutorial y todo funciono:
    ng generate component selectornumerico

3- después al generar otro componente:
    ng generate component listadoarticulos

y copiar todo el codigo de ejemplo al ejecutar el proyecto:
    ng server -o

salio un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo poco que logre entender me parece que el erroro esta en la linea 20 del archivo appcomponent.ts
como se ve en la imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La salidad de deberia verse al ejecutar el proyecto es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo codigo copiado apara el ejemplo, lo muesto en las siguientes imagenes:
 codigoCopiado 1.- 'listadoarticulos.component.ts'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigoCopiado 2.-Modificar el archivo 'listadoarticulos.component.html' de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigoCopiado 3.-   Modificar el archivo 'app.component.html' y agregamos el siguiente contenido con la definición de una etiqueta app-listadoarticulos con el enlace a la propiedad:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigoCopiado 4.-   La clase AppComponent definir la propiedad articulos que es la que se enlaza con la propiedad de la etiqueta app-listadoarticulos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

finalmente tocaria ehjecutar el proyecto:
con la salida correspondiente en el navegador como mencione antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias a quien se tome la molestia de atender mi consulta.
buen día a todos

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un segundo parametro para el ViewChild

@ViewChild(Pane, {static: false})

Referencia: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: es mas o menos lo que menciona el error, pero mas bien buco una explicacion, y el codigo exacto que deberia ir, igualmente gracias.